# How do I parse a char from a String?

Tags: java, string, temperature, charat

So I'm trying to make a temperature conversor in Java, the trick is that the user must input both the number and the temperature in the same scan (e.g "100 c") so the algorithm transforms the user given value to the 2 other measures of temperature (F° and K°). Thing is, I don't know exactly how to do that. I've tried looking up similar questions on this website and they come up with the .charAt() function, but this won't exactly work if the user inputs something like 1000 c, 10000 c, 1000000000 c or something similar.

How should I proceed?

Comment: In the same scan or in the same line? You can scan the int first and then the rest of the line to get two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you last char in String whatever the length of String is because we are getting char at position `String.legth() - 1`.

```
String input = "1000 c";
char type = input.charAt(input.length()-1);
System.out.println(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you for the safety you should use `value.trim()` function on your String value to get rid of white spaces from both ends, once you have done that you will be sure that the last character of the input is F or K  -> you can refer to the last character in your String by doing `value.charAt(value.length()-1);`